# How to Import resource from WSO2 Governace with basic Authentication?

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 Governance Registry and I need to import a new WSDL resource from an URL (e.g. http://host:8080/path/service/SOAP_SERVICE?wsdl), but the resource need to basic authentication, so when I try to import, WSO2 Governance throws an error java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://host:8080/path/service/SOAP_SERVICE?wsdl

How can I pass the credentials to the end point?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I used a WA to solve my problem.